# How do I swap these icons onHover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
        <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="icon1"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" id="icon2"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" id="icon3"></a> | 
        <span id="view_name"> 2-up</span>
    </div>
```

Assume the names of the new images follow this formula:

name + "-hover". So image1.png = image1-hover.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and just do a [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/replace) on the `src` attribute, like this:

```
$("#compv-navbar a img").hover(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace('.png', '-hover.png');
}, function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace('-hover.png', '.png');
});
```